# Table with white framework

Tags: html-table, white-framework

I am trying to access a table using white framework. I am not able to retrieve the rows/cells using it. I have done research, read documentation, stepped into the code too. I can't seem to find a way to extract just a single cell. There aren't examples/samples to look into or I couldn't find them. Any help?

```
    TableRow tr = testTable.Row("Column Name","Value in the cell");
    tr.DrawHighlight();
```

After the first statement gets executed, it raises a UIItemSearchException.

> TestStack.White.Factory.UIItemSearchException: Cannot find column with text Column Name. Found columns:(null)
>   [Error - 3:40:59 PM] 'TestStack.White.Interceptors.CoreInterceptor' Error when invoking get_Header, on Table with parameters
>   [Error - 3:46:35 PM] 'TestStack.White.Interceptors.CoreInterceptor' Error when invoking Row, on Table with parameters: Column Name, Value in the cell.